# Deleting persistent shell history

Tags: shell, command-history

Someone suggested this command to delete persistent shell history

```
history -c; >$HISTFILE
```

I just don't want to excute it before I know what it does exaclty, can you help?

Comment: What shell are you using? Is this about bash or something else?

Answer (score 3):

This is two commands, separated by `;`, not one. You have `history -c` and then you have `> $HISTFILE`. You don't specify in your question, but assuming you are using `bash`, you can run `help history` to see how the `history` command works. You will see that the `-c` option will:

```
  -c    clear the history list by deleting all of the entries
```

So `history -c` deletes all history from your current shell session.

Global history is saved in the file stored in the variable `$HISTFILE`. By default, this is `~/.bash_history`:

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/terdon/.bash_history
```

In the bash shell, the `>` redirection operator with no command will empty a file. For example:

```
$ echo "Hello world!" > file
$ cat file
Hello world!
$ > file
$ cat file
$
```

As you can see above, running `> file` emptied the file, so running `> $HISTFILE` will empty your history file.

So, taking all this together, `history -c; > $HISTFILE` will clear your current shell's history and then also delete all stored history from your user.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you :)